# How to delete TFVC repository in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc

I need to delete a **TFVC** repository in Azure DevOps, but there seems to be no option to allow me to do it. The only TFVC repository (which I just created) seems to not even have a drop-down menu:

[image]

In contrast, in the same project, Git's repositories have a "Delete Repository" option in the drop-down menu:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently, deleting TFVC repository is not allowed once it has been created.

Source: [MSDN forum's answer from Microsoft staff](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9d77231e-0679-4927-a89a-f9741b851365/how-to-delete-a-tfvc-repository?forum=tfsversioncontrol).

Answer (score 14):

When a Team Project is created as a TFVC based project, the repository is part of the "key infrastructure". The repository cannot be deleted, but it can be destroyed.

```
tf vc destroy $/TestProject
```

The UI doesn't always completely understand what happened after you have executed this command, some parts will still show the repo due to the fact that the Team Project knows it *should have* a repository with the same name.

Once destroyed the repository cannot be recreated. This is a one-time action.

If you've made the move to Git, you can always perform a mirror clone and push the complete repository to a new Team Project. You can move the work items to another project as well. Build definitions and Release Definitions can be exported+imported.

It's usually not worth it though.

Comment: Thank you for this info. "The UI doesn't always completely understand what happened after you have executed this command" will stop me from going this route as this might impact the project. But thanks anyways.

Comment: Not understand meaning it may show that there ever was a tfvc repo and that it can't access it anymore.

Comment: Would you be able to create a new TFVC repo instead with no repercussions?

Comment: No. You can't recreate a new one. This is the extermination technique.

Comment: You can always create a new team project with a new tfvc repository.

Answer (score 1):

Ok just update for Azure DevOps

the command does work

"tf vc destroy $/TestProject"

it will remove the TSVC code but it still appears in list of options with message deleted. It is not ideal but its enough to stop people using it.

Answer (score 0):

The project must have at least one repository. So, before start, make sure you have at least 2 repositories.

Steps from start:

1. Connect with VS to the project
2. Open Source Control
3. Map the repository
4. Get all the repository to local disc
5. Select the repository and delete
6. Check in

Confirm on DevOps that the repository no longer exists.